# SharePoint 2013 - Document Library Access Issues

Tags: 2013, permissions

Our SharePoint sites reflect our company structure, so each department has its own site. Sites are accessible to anyone in that department (contributor level) but some document libraries or folders in those libraries are accessible to people in other departments, access being granted at the library or folder level.

We are having a problem with this setup which never occurred on SP 2007, namely that if a user has access to a library *but not the site the library is in* they cannot check out or upload documents - they get challenged for credentials.

For example, the HR site contains lots of confidential information so is restricted to HR staff only at the site level. The site contains several document libraries, one of which (for the sake of example) contains the building facilities information, which sometimes needs to be updated by a non-HR user (User A). User A has contributor-level access to the library but no access at the site level. In SP 2007, this caused no problems and User A was able to check out, edit and upload documents. In SP 2013, User A can no longer do this. If I grant User A visitor privileges to the site, they can edit the documents in the facilities library - a workround that's no good to us as User A is *definitely* not allowed to read most of the content in that site.

Is this normal behaviour for SP2013 or have we hit a glitch of some kind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to allow a group of people access to a single list or library within a site collection without giving them access to other resources on the site collection, including the site’s home page. It is easy to break inheritance to the library, create a security group for the library and add the people to the group.

However, this has side effects that may not be intended

[Get more explanation on this link](http://words.usask.ca/sharepointsig/2013/01/22/permissions-when-giving-people-access-to-one-listlibrary/).